# Stable Manifold is tangent to the stable subspace

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

What is meant exactly by that statement?

Let's say $f: E\to E$ is a diffeomorphisms on finite dimensional space. Also let $p$ be a fixed hyperbolic point of $f$. Then denote $W$ as the stable manifold of $f$ at $p$. Now the stable manifold is just a subspace of $E$ (or technically it can be identified with one). What does it mean for a manifold (that is in E) be tangent to a subspace of $E$? My only guess is that the tangent space at $p$ on the stable manifold can be identified with the stable subspace.

Thanks

Comment: Hint: tangent space (at the given point) of a submanifold is a subspace of the tangent space of the ambient manifold (at the same point).